# How to pass data from the controller to the view in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using CodeIgniter 3 for a project and in a controller of that project I need to pass its data to a view. There are 3 functions in that controller and and I have called 2 of them into the `index()` function and passed the data from it. In the view some of the passed data is outputted and some don't. Could you please show me what's the issue?

Controller

```
<?php

class Insight extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->Model('Insight_Model');
        $data['donorcount'] = $this->Insight_Model->donorCount();
        $data['packetcount'] = $this->Insight_Model->packetCount();
        $data['packetChartData'] = $this->bloodTypesChart();
        $data['genderChartData'] =  $this->genderCountsChart();
        $this->load->view('insight', $data);

    }

    public function bloodTypesChart()
    {
        $query=" SELECT BloodType as blood_type, COUNT(PacketID) as packetcount FROM packets WHERE isAvailable = 1 GROUP BY blood_type";

        $packetChartData = [];
        $blood_types = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();

        foreach($blood_types as $row)
        {
            $packetChartData['packetLabel'][] = $row['blood_type'];
            $packetChartData['packetData'][] = $row['packetcount'];
        }
        return $packetChartData;
    }

    public function genderCountsChart()
    {
        $query=" SELECT DonorGender as donor_gender, COUNT(DonorID) as donor_count FROM donors GROUP BY donor_gender";

        $genderChartData = [];
        $genderCount = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();

        foreach($genderCount as $row)
        {
            $genderChartData['genderLabel'][] = $row['donor_gender'];
            $genderChartData['genderData'][] = $row['donor_count'];
        }
        return $genderChartData;

    }

}
```

View - In the view `$donorcount` and `$packetcount` are viewed but others don't, but if I echo the variables like this `<?php echo json_encode($packetChartData['packetLabel'])?>` outside JS it outputs `["A+","AB+","AB-","B+","B-","O+","O-"]`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assests/styles/table.css'); ?>">
    <title>Kegalle Blood Bank - Blood Types Insight</title>
</head>
<body style="margin-bottom: 50px">
<?php include_once 'navbars/navbar2.php' ?>

<?php
if (!($this->session->userdata('isStaffLoggedIn'))) {
    redirect('home/login');
}
?>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center mt-5">
            <h1>Insight</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center m-5">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card border-info mx-sm-1 p-3 shadow-lg">
                    <div class="card border-danger shadow text-danger p-3 my-card"><span class="fa fa-heart"
                                                                                         aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-danger text-center mt-3"><h4>Total Donors</h4></div>
                    <div class="text-danger text-center mt-2"><h1><?php echo $donorcount; ?></h1></div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card border-success mx-sm-1 p-3 shadow-lg">
                    <div class="card border-success shadow text-success p-3 my-card"><span class="fa fa-eye"
                                                                                           aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-success text-center mt-3"><h4>Total Available Packets</h4></div>
                    <div class="text-success text-center mt-2"><h1><?php echo $packetcount; ?></h1></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="chart-container container mb-4">
    <div class="bar-chart-container">
        <canvas id="packet-count-chart" style="background: #ecf5ec"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="chart-container container">
    <div class="doughnut-chart-container">
        <canvas id="gender-count-chart" style="background: #ecf5ec"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include_once 'footer/footer.php' ?>
</body>

<script>
    const ctx1 = document.getElementById('packet-count-chart');
    const chart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: <?php echo json_encode($packetChartData['packetLabel'])?>,
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of packets available',
                data: <?php echo json_encode($packetChartData['packetData'])?>,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive:true,
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    const ctx2 = document.getElementById('gender-count-chart');
    const chart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: <?php echo json_encode($genderChartData['genderLabel'])?>,
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of donors',
                data: <?php echo json_encode($genderChartData['genderData'])?>,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: why are you creating a new post - yesterday I corrected the code and it works. I even pasted the picture so that you could see that it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434601/view-is-being-rendered-multiple-times-in-codeigniter-3/70434799?noredirect=1#comment124513892_70434799

Comment: About what pasting are you talking about? I pasted the screenshots as you asked. I'm still facing the issue so need to resolve that somehow.

Comment: when you showed the code - I corrected it later. Check yesterday's post again

Comment: Thank you very much @WiatroBosy that was my bad I didn't notice that. The code works now with couple of changes. I will delete this post.

Comment: It's a basic question, that you can find on the documentation or even on this platform, if you have put any effort in search of the answer.